# Matplotlib Cross-Currency Format

Tags: python, matplotlib, forex

I am unable to load cross-currencies via `matplotlib`.  I am using yahoo finance to load the data.  On Yahoo's website, a symbol such as EUR/USD is `EURUSD=X`.

However, trying to pull the ticker `EURUSD=X` returns with a 404 error. The only way I have found to load any sort of currency-based instrument is using `EUR=X`, however, these only return `$USD` based instruments.

I am having issues loading symbols such as `EUR/JPY`, or `AUD/CHF`. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Here is the code I am using to pull a historical instrument:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.finance as finance
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager

startdate = datetime.date(2005,1,1)
today = enddate = datetime.date.today()
ticker = raw_input('Enter Instrument: ')

fh = finance.fetch_historical_yahoo(ticker, startdate, enddate)
# a numpy record array with fields: date, open, high, low, close, volume, adj_close)

r = mlab.csv2rec(fh); fh.close()
r.sort()
```

Comment: Can you show us some code of what you have tried?  At some point yahoo changed their url format so you may be having some issues with that as well.  I suggest you look at the code in `matplotlib.finance`, iirc the code that grabs the historical quotes is only a few lines.  Copy that out and figure out how to fix it.

Comment: I have updated the original post.  I will look into what you suggested tcaswell, thanks!